# Expanding encryption and decryption

Tags: c, encryption, openssl

```
 #include <openssl/rsa.h>
    #include <openssl/pem.h>
    #include <openssl/err.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    #define KEY_LENGTH  2048
   #define PUB_EXP     3
    #define PRINT_KEYS
    #define WRITE_TO_FILE

int main(void) {
size_t pri_len;            // Length of private key
size_t pub_len;            // Length of public key
char   *pri_key;           // Private key
char   *pub_key;           // Public key
char   msg[KEY_LENGTH/8];  // Message to encrypt
char   *encrypt = NULL;    // Encrypted message
char   *decrypt = NULL;    // Decrypted message
 char   *err;               // Buffer for any error messages

// Generate key pair
printf("Generating RSA (%d bits) keypair...", KEY_LENGTH);
fflush(stdout);
RSA *keypair = RSA_generate_key(KEY_LENGTH, PUB_EXP, NULL, NULL);

// To get the C-string PEM form:
BIO *pri = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
BIO *pub = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());

PEM_write_bio_RSAPrivateKey(pri, keypair, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
PEM_write_bio_RSAPublicKey(pub, keypair);

pri_len = BIO_pending(pri);
pub_len = BIO_pending(pub);

pri_key = malloc(pri_len + 1);
pub_key = malloc(pub_len + 1);

BIO_read(pri, pri_key, pri_len);
BIO_read(pub, pub_key, pub_len);

pri_key[pri_len] = '\0';
pub_key[pub_len] = '\0';

#ifdef PRINT_KEYS
    printf("\n%s\n%s\n", pri_key, pub_key);
#endif
printf("done.\n");

// Get the message to encrypt
printf("Message to encrypt: ");
fgets(msg, KEY_LENGTH-1, stdin);
msg[strlen(msg)-1] = '\0';

// Encrypt the message
encrypt = malloc(RSA_size(keypair));
int encrypt_len;
err = malloc(130);
if((encrypt_len = RSA_public_encrypt(strlen(msg)+1, (unsigned char*)msg, (unsigned char*)encrypt,
                                     keypair, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING)) == -1) {
    ERR_load_crypto_strings();
    ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), err);
    fprintf(stderr, "Error encrypting message: %s\n", err);
    goto free_stuff;
}

#ifdef WRITE_TO_FILE
// Write the encrypted message to a file
    FILE *out = fopen("out.bin", "w");
    fwrite(encrypt, sizeof(*encrypt),  RSA_size(keypair), out);
    fclose(out);
    printf("Encrypted message written to file.\n");
    free(encrypt);
    encrypt = NULL;

    // Read it back
    printf("Reading back encrypted message and attempting decryption...\n");
    encrypt = malloc(RSA_size(keypair));
    out = fopen("out.bin", "r");
    fread(encrypt, sizeof(*encrypt), RSA_size(keypair), out);
    fclose(out);
#endif

// Decrypt it
decrypt = malloc(encrypt_len);
if(RSA_private_decrypt(encrypt_len, (unsigned char*)encrypt, (unsigned char*)decrypt,
                       keypair, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING) == -1) {
    ERR_load_crypto_strings();
    ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), err);
    fprintf(stderr, "Error decrypting message: %s\n", err);
    goto free_stuff;
}
printf("Decrypted message: %s\n", decrypt);

free_stuff:
RSA_free(keypair);
BIO_free_all(pub);
BIO_free_all(pri);
free(pri_key);
free(pub_key);
free(encrypt);
free(decrypt);
free(err);

return 0;

}
```

Im trying to expand on this code that will allow the user to encrypt any textfile and decrypt the textfile. Ive tried to expand on it including other coding but i dont even know where to start. just trying to seek any help i can find.

Comment: RSA, asymmetric encryption, is not designed to encrypt data, it is designed to have two keys, one to encrypt and another to decrypt. Generally it is used to encrypt other encryption keys. Note that RSA is very slow and the data size is limited to less than the key size so with a 2048-bit key the data is limited to less than 256-bytes. Nor is performing multiple serial encryptions to accommodate larger data acceptable. The usual solution is to encrypt data with a symmetric algorithm such as AES and if necessary to encrypt that key with RSA (or ECC).

Comment: @zaph hmm so its not possible for this code to allow a user to encrypt some textfile because the data size is limited with the 2048 key? In this particular code once it runs it allows the user to type in whatever message they want to encrypt and it will decrpyt. What if i just wanted to set the option up where the user choose to lets see press "1" to encrypt and it will just prompt them to type whatever message in then press "2" to decrypt and shows the decrypted message?

Comment: I told you where to start in a comment on your other question: move your encryption/decryption code into a function that takes arguments and returns a result. Is there something *specific* that you need help with? "I don't know where to start" is generally not well-received here, especially when it doesn't look like you've made any attempts of your own.

Comment: Secure message encryption is very hard, there are only a few that are known to be trusted and only two I would trust. Do not create yet another insecure message app, just use [Signal](https://whispersystems.org) or iMessages.

Comment: @Wyzard yea specifically what part of the encode/decode would i have to move into a new function? would i just take both and put them into 1 function and call from there?

Comment: That's up to you.  It'd make sense to put encryption and decryption in different functions, so that the program is able to do just one or just the other, but if it only needs to encrypt and then immediately decrypt, having them both in the same function will work.

Comment: And actually, if you just need it to process a single file each time the program is run, you don't actually *need* to move the crypto stuff into a separate function.  You could just replace the "get the message to encrypt" part with code that reads a file.  But it's not clear what (specifically) you actually want the program to do, so nobody can give you clear advice on how it should be changed.

Comment: @Wyzard ultimately just have the problem encrypt a text or textfile then decrypt it. Something like "press 1 to encrypt" then "press 2 to decrypt" essentially

Comment: That's the sort of information that belongs *in the question*, with *details*, not in a comment two days later that'll require further back-and-forth to figure out exactly what you need.  You still haven't identified a specific problem that you're looking for help with.  Please read "[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"

Comment: Based on your comment about studying for finals in your earlier question about this code (and since you'd forgotten how to run a program after compiling it), I suspect this is an assignment, and the crypto code was written by your professor.  It's not clear that you've written *any* code of your own, and it sounds like you have no idea how to do your assignment and you're looking for someone to spoon-feed you a solution.  People aren't going to be interested in helping you if you don't make any effort of your own.